# JQuery: .on("select") instead of .on("change")?

Tags: jquery, select, dom-events

I currently listen change in a select but I would like to listen when user select an option

I use JQuery and try to use `.on('select')` but it does not work

**JS**

```
$("#patients").on("change",function(event){ 
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#patients").data("patient-url"),
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                'patient' : $(this).val(),  
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                // alert(data)
                $("#information_patient").html(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: You can listen to "click" when you want to capture the moment *right after* the user picks an option. "click" will also fire when the user makes a choice with the keyboard.

Comment: I think "click" will fire before on option is picked

Comment: Please explain what problem you're trying to solve. Selecting an element is not the same as selecting an option.